# Show a ProgressDialog inside a WebView

Tags: android, webview

i have searched but i cant find a case to implement my webview, my webview dosnt open a webpage, it just loads an html that i have, so i need a progressbar before the data appears, i have declared a progressBar inside my layout and this is the code i have to show the html inside webview

```
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pBar);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", indicadores.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

XML

```
<WebView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/webview"/>
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:id="@+id/pBar"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

what is the best approach to show the progressBar before showing the result.

Thanks

Comment: put your layout xml in your question

Answer (score 0):

In a browser with a progress bar the progress increments as components are loaded over the network.

If you have all of the webview data locally there's no progress to report. There's not going to be any place where you'll be able to increment the progress. You'd need the webview to be able to report it's rendering progress, and that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have your own html file and need to display it using web-view only,This page can't take much time for render. so, if you want to put progress bar effect than you can use runnable.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int waitingTime = 2000; // mSec.
private Handler winHandler = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    initWebView();
}

private void initWebView() {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", indicadores.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    }
};



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    winHandler = new Handler();
    winHandler.postDelayed(runnable, waitingTime);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (winHandler != null) {
        winHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

}

here, waiting time is **2sec** you can change it as per you need.